# (Officially retired) ESRI Silverlight API

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I have a client with a web GIS app based on the now retired ESRI Silverlight API.

Eventually we will be replacing this app with a javascript based alternative, but for now we want to be able to load in layers from CSV, KML and WMS which apparently is possible via an additional assembly (ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources)
i.e.

https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/api-reference/#ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.CsvLayer.html

This is obviously not available officially via ESRI anymore, and the client cannot find the original download of the API. All we have is a .NET app with the relevant assemblies (but not the one I need) added as a reference.

Does anyone know where these retired API downloads are still available?

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-toolkit-sl-wpf/tree/master/src/Silverlight/API ?  The csvlayer looks like it's in a common API https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-toolkit-sl-wpf/blob/master/src/CommonAPI/API/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources/CsvLayer/CsvLayer.cs

Comment: Duh!!, didn't think to look in Github.....
I'll grab that and hopefully it'll all... just.... work....
Many thanks Kirk